# ¿Por qué no puedo instalar Eclipse Color Theme?

Tags: eclipse, permisos

El problema es que no puedo instalar el complemento [***Eclipse Color Theme***](http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com).

Me sale este error:

> Problem Ocurred
>
> Unable to read repository at http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update
>
> Acceso denegado

Comment: Intenta ejecutar eclipse con permisos de administrador. Verifica que no haya algo que bloquee la descarga de datos del plugin a tu equipo.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar una captura de lo que aparece en el botón `Details>>`?

Answer (score 0):

cambiaron el nombre de su repositorio a "http://eclipse-color-theme.github.io/update". Instalalo de forma manual solo asi funciona. Si vas directo a los plugins esta te da el error en el repositorio "http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update"